# Omnipay, paypal REST with laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, laravel-5, omnipay

The response i keep getting at `dd($finalResponse);` is:

```
RestResponse {#298 ▼
  #statusCode: 400
  #request: RestCompletePurchaseRequest {#300 ▶}
  #data: array:4 [▼
    "name" => "PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION"
    "message" => "Payer has not approved payment"
    "information_link" => "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#PAYMENT_NOT_APPROVED_FOR_EXECUTION"
    "debug_id" => "5471589613718"
  ]
}
```

Here is the code.

```
$gateway = Omnipay::create('PayPal_Rest');

    // Initialise the gateway
    $gateway->initialize(array(
       'clientId' => env('PAYMENT_SANDBOX_PAYPAL_CLIENTID'),
       'secret'   => env('PAYMENT_SANDBOX_PAYPAL_SECRET'),
       'testMode' => true, // Or false when you are ready for live transactions
    ));

    // Do an authorisation transaction on the gateway
    $transaction = $gateway->authorize(array(
        'returnUrl'=> env('PAYMENT_SANDBOX_PAYPAL_URL'),
        'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/cancel',
       'amount'        => '10.00',
       'currency'      => 'AUD',
       'description'   => 'This is a test authorize transaction.',
       // 'card'          => $card,
    ));

    $response = $transaction->send();
    if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
       // Find the authorization ID
       $authResponse = $response->getTransactionReference();
       echo "Authorize transaction was successful!\n".$authResponse;
    }else{
        echo "Failed to auth transaction";
        dd($response);
    }

    // Once the transaction has been approved, we need to complete it.
    $transaction = $gateway->completePurchase(array(
        'payerId'             => $request->PayerID,
        'transactionReference' => $authResponse            
    ));

    $finalResponse = $transaction->send();

    dd($finalResponse);

    if ($finalResponse->getData()) {
       echo "Transaction was successful!\n";
       // Find the authorization ID
       $results = $finalResponse->getTransactionReference();
        dd($results);
    }else{
        dd($finalResponse->getData());
    }
```

After logging in as the payer and completing purchase, what else does the payer need to approve and how?

Answer (score 12):

No, you aren't understanding the PayPal payment flow correctly.  Here is the correct flow:

1. You do the call to Omnipay::create(), $gateway->initialize() and $gateway->authorize() just like you have them above.  However for returnUrl you have to provide a URL on your site, just like you have for cancelUrl.  Perhaps you mean to use http://localhost:8000/return (although better would be to have a transaction ID or something in the return URL).
2. The response from the $gateway->authorize() will be of type RedirectResponse.  You can check this:

// Do an authorisation transaction on the gateway

```
$transaction = $gateway->authorize(array(
    'returnUrl'=> env('PAYMENT_SANDBOX_PAYPAL_URL'),
    'cancelUrl' => 'http://localhost:8000/cancel',
    'amount'        => '10.00',
    'currency'      => 'AUD',
    'description'   => 'This is a test authorize transaction.',
    // 'card'          => $card,
));

$response = $transaction->send();
if ($response->isRedirect()) {
    // Yes it's a redirect.  Redirect the customer to this URL:
    $redirectUrl = $response->getRedirectUrl();
}
```

At that point the initial handshake with the customer is over.  You have now redirected the customer to the PayPal web site where they will authorize the transaction by logging in with their PayPal account email address and password, check the invoice, click the button that says that they agree to pay.

The next thing that happens is that the customer is redirected by PayPal back to your web site, on the redirectUrl that you provided in the authorize() call.  That will jump to a different place in your code.  At that point you call completeAuthorize, just like you had in your code earlier:

```
// Once the transaction has been approved, we need to complete it.
$transaction = $gateway->completePurchase(array(
    'payerId'             => $request->PayerID,
    'transactionReference' => $authResponse            
));

$finalResponse = $transaction->send();

dd($finalResponse);

if ($finalResponse->getData()) {
   echo "Transaction was successful!\n";
   // Find the authorization ID
   $results = $finalResponse->getTransactionReference();
    dd($results);
}else{
    dd($finalResponse->getData());
}
```

Note that you need to have stored the Payer ID and transactionReference from the authorize call and be able to recover those in your returnUrl code.

You also need to be able to handle the cancelUrl case, where the customer has decided not to agree to the payment on PayPal and gets sent back to the cancelUrl URL on your website instead.

Finally you need to be able to handle the occasional cases where the customer completes the payment on the PayPal web site but does not end back on your returnUrl.  This could be because of a network issue, the browser crashed, or because the customer closed their browser between clicking "Agree to Pay" on PayPal and landing back on your site.  The best way to handle those is with the omnipay-paypal calls fetchPurchase() or listPurchase().

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation, at least now there is information for others to use. 

This however is not something i wish on my enemy let alone my customers. There is a solution that i used previously that skipped the approval process. I will post here when it's complete for others that may be interested.

Comment: Harry, it's on my list of things to do to update the documentation for the omnipay-paypal module to improve clarity on what has to happen for redirect payments. Although redirect payments are handled generically by Omnipay, PayPal appears to be the gateway that people most commonly use that requires a redirect. Others such as VTPayments (for UnionPay and AliPay China payments) also require redirects just like the above, but are less frequently used. Anyway I will submit some PRs to Kayla and they will got through the normal review & approval process.

Comment: That's why i am switching to PayPal_Express, the PayPal_Rest process has a native UX issue in my opinion, caused by PayPal